# transferFrom error

Tags: solidity

Am I completely losing it here?

```
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= _balances[from]);
    require(value <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(value);

    uint256 tokensToBurn = findOnePercent(value);
    uint256 tokensToTransfer = value.sub(tokensToBurn);

    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(tokensToTransfer);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokensToBurn);

    _allowed[from][msg.sender] = _allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(value);

    emit Transfer(from, to, tokensToTransfer);
    emit Transfer(from, address(0), tokensToBurn);

    return true;
  }
```

This is the transferFrom function verbatim from the Bomb contract. When adding the approval, it doesn't seem to work, on remix compiler 0.5.0 and 0.5.17. Yet somehow this transferFrom works with exchanges. Is there something that remix is upset about, like missing a payable modifier despite the fact the contract works out in the wild?

Comment: What is the approval code?!

Comment: function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(spender != address(0));
    _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;
  }

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1c95b093d6c236d3ef7c796fe33f9cc6b8606714#code

Comment: Then what do you mean by "When adding approval..."?! Do you mean `require(value <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);`?!